# How do I use react-native-image-marker package(a package not documented in Expo packages) in Expo project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I exported the project from react-native CLI to expo, now there is a package(react-native-image-marker) I used to create watermark on images in the former react-native CLI project but now I need that same functionality using this package (react-native-image-marker) in expo.

*I am Using the "Managed workflow" can this native module work in it?
some native modules do work in expo though.*

**please any help as to how I can go about this? or How to use react-native-image-marker in expo?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no similar library. If you want to use the expo, you have to run the [expo prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/).